# Django model with exactly 2 users references

Tags: python, django, model

I want to define a 'Game' model in which exactly (and not more) 2 users will compete. Each of this user can compete in another game in parallel or later. I thought about a Manytomanyfield, but I don't know how to restrict the number of users. How to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just add two user fields.

```
class Game(models.Model):
    game_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    first_player = models.ForeignKey(User)
    second_player = models.ForeignKey(User)

    winner = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='winner')
```

Answer (score 0):

Just create a model with two user fields (player1, player2).

Comment: You need to give a reason when answering a question. New answers without any explanation how they complement other answers tend to get deleted in the review process.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).